# How can I add a specific sub-set list of customer contacts to the body of an email template message?

Tags: email, email-template

I want to have a SFDC email template say something like this:

> Hi Customer Admin,
>
> Please check the following list of contacts and verify that blah is
>   blah.
>
> - 1@foo.example
> - 2@foo.example
> - 3@foo.example
>
> Thanks,
>
> Blah.

The list of email addresses should be pulled from the contacts for the customer account that match a specific attribute (have a field value set for the contact).

Is this possible? The field merge value feature seems like it can only pull singular static values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with a [Visualforce template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_intro.htm):

```
<ul>
    <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Contacts}" var="contact">
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!contact.SomeField='Some Value'}">
            <li>{!contact.Email}</li>
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:repeat>
</ul>
```

You cannot do this with a plain text or HTML template, as they do not allow loops.